# how to get vender id of my phone to debugging android project in real device

Tags: android

I'm using Eclipse Kepler on Linux Ubuntu 14.04. When I run my Android project in the emulator it works fine but when I connect my android *intex aqua curve mini* it doesn't get recognized by Eclipse.
When I google about this problem I came to the conclusion that I need vendor id of my phone that wasn't listed in http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html.

How to run my project on my Android device?

How can I get Eclipse to recognize the target?

Comment: i think appropriate drivers isnt installed , i have connect aqua on windows with mobogene software

Comment: thank you sir ....actually i got the solution which is quite impressive

Comment: what is the solution?mobogenie?

Comment: no mobogenie i got another one for linux ubuntu.....i save all vender id rule of android

Comment: ohk will that work for china mibiles in ubnutu?

Comment: android then might work